# ReactJS/Django How to encode search string into onClick button to redirect to exact URL?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect, react-router-v4

Noob in ReactJS and Django here.
I have to model a website for a school project and we are using ReactJS for frontend and Django for backend. The app currently runs fine, but I encountered a problem to redirect my Search Button to the exact search page I need.

Here is what I want to do exactly:

1. User types in a string in the SearchBar. For example, types in: hello.
2. User presses the SearchButton.
3. The SearchButton will redirect the user to this EXACT path/url:

   http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/?q=hello

Currently, this is what I have:

```
export class SearchBar extends React.Component {

render() {
    return (
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search questions here" 
            id="query" name="/search/?q="/>
            <input type="submit" value="Search" 

        onclick="onLoadConfigPress(document.getElementById(name).value)" />
        </form>
      );
    }
  }
```

What this redirects me to is:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/?%2Fsearch%2F%3Fq%3D=ss
```

Clearly, that is not equal to:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/?q=hello
```

Because the onClick does not accept special characters from parameter "name", which are the chars: /     /? =

So, my question is, is there a way to encode this "name" parameter, something like stringify() or EncodeUIC() or another easier way to redirect the SearchButton to the exact url?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

I believe you first have to read and learn how react works, so you can get better results and not run into that kind of issues

first of all, I do not think this is ok, do you have onLoadConfigPress function and name variable globally? where do they come from?

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search questions here" 
    id="query" name="/search/?q="/>
    <input type="submit" value="Search" 

onclick="onLoadConfigPress(document.getElementById(name).value)" />
</form>
```

You can refactor that to

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
   <input 
      type="text" 
      placeholder="Search questions here" 
      onChange={this.handleChange}
    />
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

where *handleSubmit* and *handleChange* are methods of your class Component *SearchBar*

Below you can find and example of your component and its functionality in the react way of doing it

```
class SearchBar extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      search : '',
      url : '',
      redirect : false
    }
    // binding the context to the SearchBar 
    // because this functions will be executed in a 
    // different context
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSearch = this.handleSearch.bind(this);
  }
  // Modify the search key of the component state
  handleChange (e) {
    this.setState({
      search : e.target.value
    });
  }
  // gets the user input
  // and build the url based on it
  handleSearch (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent page reload
    const { search } = this.state;
    const url = `your_url/search/?q=${encodeURIComponent(search)}`;


    console.log(url)
    // What do you want to do?
    // if fetch data based on the url
    // then make an http called using fetch
    // and update the state of your component 
    // using setState method

    // if redirect (assuming your have a SPA and using react router dom)
    // use
    // this.setState({
    //   url,
    //   redirect : true
    // });
    // that will force your component to rerender
  }

  render () {
    const { search, url, redirect } = this.state;
    // if you are using react-router-dom just 
    // render a Redirect Component
    // if (redirect) {
    //    return <Redirect to={url} />
    // }
    //
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSearch}>
        <input 
          value={search}
          onChange={this.handleChange}/>
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
I am indeed new to this and I actually had something similar to this on another version I had, but I could not make it work.

I used your code and it actually ran. However, when I type in the SearchBar and press the SearchButton, it does not redirect to any url. The page does not render/change, it turns blank (a white page) when I press it, while staying on the same URL as it was before. 

Any ideas why? I added the Route into my App.js file too.

Comment: no problem, but I do not know how your code looks like, I gave you answer for the question you asked

Comment: check your browser console for errors that usually helps to find out what's going wrong

Comment: Would you be able to quickly glance over my code? It is available on my GitHub.

The SearchBar component is here:
https://github.com/anthonyle17/question/blob/master/stack_overfull/frontend/src/components/SearchBar/index.jsx

and the App.js is here:
https://github.com/anthonyle17/question/blob/master/stack_overfull/frontend/src/App.js

Comment: you forgot to import Redirect component from react-router-dom. Instead of  import {withRouter} from "react-router-dom" use import {withRouter, Redirect} from "react-router-dom"

Comment: since my answer solved your issue, can you please mark it as correct?

Comment: I actually did that and it still redirects me to a blank page! In fact, it does not redirect (because the url does not change), it just blanks the page

Answer (score 0):

For encoding and decoding uri strings are:

```
encodeURIComponent(url)
decodeURIComponent(url)
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuricomponent.asp

Hopefully that will help.